# angular-strap timepicker saves different time

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datetime, timepicker, angular-strap

I am using angular-strap to save date and time for a project, but the time being displayed is not the same time being saved.  I can not find any information anywhere on fixing this issue.  Has anyone else had this problem?!
[Screen shot of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1GIN.png)

Comment: The Z after your time is for Zulu (not time zone adjusted). The Time Object can be used to return either date format.

Comment: I have the same problem, except my angularstrap timepicker shows 07:00 when the actual value is "1970-01-01T06:00:00.000Z". Did you manage to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The value `2015-04-21T09:00:00.000Z` means we are talking about the specific point in time described as "The 21. of April in the year 2015, at 9 o'clock UTC". That is, it includes a **time zone** denoted by the trailing `Z`. The timepicker you use automatically **presents** that value to the user, the exact same **point in time**, but takes the time zone his system is set to into account.

**TL;DR** The value is correct. Use this value for calculations and store this value in your database. Whenever you present this value to a user, convert it to his time zone.